# The legacy Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM) API is deprecated. what does it mean

Tags: firebase-cloud-messaging

I received a message from Google saying:

> We’re writing to remind you that starting June 20, 2024 the legacy Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM) APIs will be discontinued.

I have some questions regarding the above.

1. Will Message completely stop migrating on June 21st?
   Or is there a transition period where I can continue to use it after June 21st?
2. Will I be unable to receive messages after migration unless I update the client SDK?

Several projects have already completed the transition to the FCMv1 protocol.
Applied server and client updates according to the migration guide.

Answer (score 2):

*firebaser here*

The versioned HTTP v1 API was [introduced all the way back in 2017](https://firebase.blog/posts/2017/11/whats-new-with-fcm-customizing-messages/), and improves on the older API in many ways. After many years of supporting both APIs, Firebase announced in June 2023 that the legacy API will be removed.

---

From the documentation on [migrating to the HTTP v1 API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/migrate-v1):

> Apps using the deprecated FCM legacy APIs for HTTP and XMPP should migrate to the HTTP v1 API at the earliest opportunity. Sending messages (including upstream messages) with those APIs was deprecated on June 20, 2023, and **will be removed in June 2024.**

So we're already in the transition period, and to ensure your apps continue to function, you should complete the documented steps as soon as possible - but definitely before June.

---

The only API that changes as part of this is the server-side API for **sending** messages. If you check the documentation you'll also see that no updates to client-side application code are required.

Comment: thank you for confirming that "no updates to client-side application code are required"! as I have an android app published, I received an email saying that the minimum recommended FCM SDK version for Android is 23.1.2. Does this mean that any app targeting a version less than this might face some issues receiving notifications?