# Firebase Cloud Messaging API HTTP v1 migration

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

We are using FCM normally.
I am curious if there is anything special that needs to be done in the app(iOS & Android & Flutter) when migrating from existing HTTP to HTTP v1.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mnVw1.png)

I looked up the official Firebase documentation, and it said to update payloads, endpoints, etc. only on the server side.

Answer (score 0):

The migration described [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/migrate-v1) only affects the API calls to **send** messages. It does not affect any client-side APIs or components that are used to **receive** messages.

Also see the last section of my (longer) answer here: [The legacy Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM) API is deprecated. what does it mean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78024354/the-legacy-firebase-cloud-messaging-fcm-api-is-deprecated-what-does-it-mean/78024465#78024465)

Answer (score 0):

Your developers failed to follow best practices and use Google client libraries to interact with Google Services.

**Do not migrate to the HTTPv1 API. Instead, Use The Firebase Admin SDK.**

> #### Options for interacting with FCM servers include the following:
>
> - The Firebase Admin SDK, which has support for Node, Java, Python, C#,
>   and Go.
> - The FCM HTTP v1 API, a REST API with secure authorization and
>   flexible cross-platform messaging capabilities (the Firebase Admin SDK
>   is based on this protocol and provides all of its inherent
>   advantages).